# C# Excel .SaveAs - Do I need to wait for process to be completed?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

After I do a `.SaveAs`, do I need to make sure the excel file is saved before I close it and release the objects? If so, how? See code below:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application()
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
Excel.WOrksheet xlWorksheet;

string xlPath = @"C:\excelfile.xlsx";

//Do sexy stuffs to the excel file

xlWorkbook.SaveAs(xlPath);

//Do I need the following?
while (!File.Existts(xlPath))
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

xlWorkbook.Close()
xlApp.Quit();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);
```

Comment: I think you don't need it because it looks like a synchronous method, can you test it yourself? And also, the file exists checking will not work as you've planned if the file already exists and waiting to be overwritten.

Comment: I'm not sure how to test that. Add thousands of lines of data into the excel and see if it can be saved?
As for the file existence you mentioned, before this code I have already made sure there is no existing file. The code is **always** creating a new excel file.

Comment: Measure the time it takes for this line to run. If it is slow (like at least hundreds of milliseconds) then you (most probably) don't need to wait. This is especially true if the time increases with the size of the excel file.

Comment: @Alireza, can I use stopwatch for that? `.Start()` before that line, and `.Stop()` after that line?

Comment: I concur with @Hendry. The Office object models are for the most part synchronous. I've never, in 25 years, heard of problems with Close and Quit following SaveAs, no matter how large or complex the file. I pretty sure you don't have to worry and don't need `Sleep`.

Comment: Thank you @CindyMeister!

Comment: i have this problem with a worksheet copy save... if the save happens too slow the new name gets assigned to my originating workbook